# How to Display Best Time in an iOS Game with 3 Significant Digits Decimal Value?

Tags: ios, swift

I am saving the best time in my iOS Game using the following functions:-

```
func format(timeInterval: TimeInterval) -> String {
let interval = Int(timeInterval)
let seconds = interval % 60
let minutes = (interval / 60) % 60
let milliseconds = Int(timeInterval * 1000) % 1000
return String(format: "%02d:%02d.%03d", minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
}

func setBestTime(with time: Int){
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let previousBestTime = defaults.integer(forKey: "bestTime")
    defaults.set(time > previousBestTime ? time : previousBestTime, forKey: "bestTime")
}

func getBestTime(){
    self.bestTimeLabel.text = "\(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "bestTime"))"
}

func gameOver() {
stopGame()
setBestTime(with: Int(elapsedTime))
}
```

But, it displays the best time in integer. I want the best time to be displayed in decimal with 3 significant figures. Could anyone please let me know how can I do that? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't calling your `format` function. You simply need to pass the `Int` value retrieve from `UserDefault` to `format` before displaying it on your label.

You should also use `UserDefaults.double` if you want to store a `TimeInterval` rather than an `Int`.

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let bestTimeKey = "bestTime"

func format(timeInterval: TimeInterval) -> String {
    let interval = Int(timeInterval)
    let seconds = interval % 60
    let minutes = (interval / 60) % 60
    let milliseconds = Int(timeInterval * 1000) % 1000
    return String(format: "%02d:%02d.%03d", minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
}

func setBestTime(with time: TimeInterval){
    let previousBestTime = defaults.double(forKey: bestTimeKey)
    defaults.set(max(time, previousBestTime), forKey: bestTimeKey)
}

func getBestTime() {
    let bestTime = defaults.double(forKey: bestTimeKey)
    let formattedBestTime = format(timeInterval: bestTime)
    bestTimeLabel.text = formattedBestTime
}

func gameOver() {
    stopGame()
    setBestTime(with: elapsedTime)
}
```

Comment: What about the setBestTime function?

Comment: Add a guard to check if the last time is less then the stored time otherwise return. No need to set the same value again

Comment: Thanks for the help! Appreciate it:)